# SQLPackage deploy a dacpac file using Universal Authentication

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, dacpac, sqlpackage

I have an Azure DevOps YAML pipeline that is currently deploying my Azure SQL database with SQLPackage.exe and SQL Authentication with pretty standard command:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"mydb01.dacpac" /TargetServerName:"mysqlserver.database.windows.net" /TargetDatabaseName:"mydb01" /TargetUser:"sqladmin" /TargetPassword:"mypwd"
```

I now want to create db users that can connect with "Azure Active Directory - Universal with MFA" option in SSMS. For that a service account has been created in Azure AD and assigned as "Azure Active Directory admin" under Azure SQL Server configuration in Azure Portal.

The SQL database project has users created with this command:

```
CREATE USER [user01@mydomain.com]
FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER 
WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;

ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [user01@mydomain.com]
```

Deploying the .dacpac file with previous command results in this error, which is understandable:

> Principal 'user01@mydomain.com' could not be created. Only
> connections established with Active Directory accounts can create
> other Active Directory users

If I use this command locally from my laptop to deploy the database:

```
SqlPackage.exe /Action:Publish /SourceFile:"mydb01.dacpac" /TargetServerName:"mysqlserver.database.windows.net" /TargetDatabaseName:"mydb01" /ua:True /tid:mydomain.onmicrosoft.com
```

an Interactive pop-up is shown where I now input credentials for the AAD admin for this Azure SQL Server and deployment works and afterwards the domain user "User01" can connect to the database using Universal Authentication with MFA.

Now the real question is how can I avoid this Interactive Pop-up, as I want to have this automated without the need to input credentials? I want automate the database deployment in my Azure DevOps YAML pipeline by using AAD integration.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set up something called a [Service Connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml) in Azure DevOps and give it the permissions it needs to read and write to the database.  When you have created the service connection it will appear in the dropdown for 'Azure Subscriptions' which appears when you click the Settings bit in YAML:

[image]

It will need `db_owner` permissions on the database and reader permissions on the AD.  You may need some help from your AD admins.  This will avoid the following error:

```
Server identity does not have Azure Active Directory Readers permission
```

A simple example:

```
  - task: SqlAzureDacpacDeployment@1
    displayName: 'Deploy dacpac to dedicated SQL Pool'
    inputs:
      azureSubscription: 'some_service_connection'
      AuthenticationType: 'servicePrincipal'
      ServerName: 'someServer'
      DatabaseName: 'someDatabase'
      deployType: 'DacpacTask'
      DeploymentAction: 'Publish'
      DacpacFile: 'C:\a\1\...someDacpac.dacpac'
      IpDetectionMethod: 'AutoDetect'

  dependsOn: Build
```

We had to wait to get this set up, particularly the AAD bit so early on I decoupled AAD security from the database project and did them as one-off manual deployments per environment as a workaround.

Comment: I have a Service Prinicipal created for in my Azure AD. Can I use this Service Principal and assign as the Azure Active Directory admin in Azure Portal, under SQL Server configuration? Then it should have ALL the required permissions on the database? Otherwise I don't know how I can assign this Service Prinicipal as db_owner. My plan was actually to try the YAML task that you have pasted. Is there a way to determine if an Service Prinicipal has reader access in Azure AD?

Comment: Yeah, run the pipeline using that service principal, create an AAD user / group and see if you get that error or not.  You should have a group as the AAD admin, and you could make that service principal a member of that group, maybe.

Comment: I've added the ADO task and added the Service Principal as Global Admin on the SQL Server. When I run the pipeline I got this error: "'user01mydomain.com' could not be resolved. Error message: 'Server identity is not configured. Please follow the steps in "Assign 
##[error]an Azure AD identity to your server and add Directory Reader permission to your identity" (https://aka.ms/sqlaadsetup)'
Error SQL72045: Script execution error.  The executed script:
CREATE USER [user01@mydomain.com] FOR EXTERNAL PROVIDER;

Comment: Have you followed the steps in that article?

Comment: I have created a System Assigned Identity for the SQL Server. I can find the Identity in AAD but I cannot figure out how to assign this Identity the role "Directory Readers" in AAD.

Comment: Do you have access to your orgs AAD?

Comment: How you getting on with this?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I have made it work thx to your suggestion. In short I use the ADO task with service principal authentication. I setup the ADO principal to be the Azure Actice Directory Admin my SQL server. This made the connection valid from ADO task to the database and I could deploy the database. Then I enables System Managed Identity on the SQL Server and to this I assigner Directory Readers role in AAD. After this my deployment could create users automatically with AAD authentication. Thx for the help.